# How to add bracket at beginning and ending in text on UNIX

Tags: unix, text, process

I have a text file of million lines to precess on UNIX as below:

```
"item"
"item"
"item"
"item"
```

And I use `sed -i "s/$/,/g" filename > new_file` to add comma at the end of each line.

What I expected is this way:

```
["item",
"item",
"item",
"item"]
```

Now, I am just using Vim to edit manually. Is there anyway to add brackets at the beginning and ending automatically with removing the comma at last line? So that, I could write a bash script to process these text files neatly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -e '1s/^/[/' -e 's/$/,/' -e '$s/,$/]/' file_name > new_file
```

The only funny bit is replacing the comma added to the last line with the close square bracket.

Also note that using `-i` means there will be no output to standard output.  Either use `-i` or use I/O redirection but not both.  (And if you're a portability nut — like me — note that Mac OS X or BSD `sed` supports `-i` but requires a suffix for the backup.  It will quite happily use `-e` as the suffix, if there's a `-e` after the `-i`, or use the `sed` script if you don't specify a `-e` — but then it complains about the file name not being a valid `sed` script).

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!! And, I like your replacing approach for the last comma.

Comment: osx: sed -i '' -e '...' file_name