# csvkit in2csv - how to convert a single json object to two-column csv

Tags: csvkit

Looking for a one liner with csvkit.

From a plain json object

```
{
  "whatever": 2342,
  "otherwise": 119,
  "and": 1,
  "so": 2,
  "on": 3
}
```

Want this csv

```
whatever,2342
otherwise,119
and,1
so,2
on,3
```

I basically want this command to work, but it doesn't.

```
echo $the_json | in2csv -f json
> When converting a JSON document with a top-level dictionary element, a key must be specified.
```

Seems like something csvkit can do, and I just haven't found the right options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## short answer

**variant A: `in2csv` (csvkit) + `csvtool`**

- wrap your json in brackets
- use `in2csv`'s `-I` option to avoid unexpected behavior
- use a command to [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the two-row CSV, e.g. [csvtool](http://colin.maudry.com/csvtool-manual-page/)

```
echo "[$the_json]" | in2csv -I -f json | csvtool transpose -
```

**variant B: use `jq` instead**

This is a solution using only `jq`: (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
echo "$the_json" | jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | @csv'
```

taken from [How to map an object to arrays so it can be converted to csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181467/how-to-map-an-object-to-arrays-so-it-can-be-converted-to-csv#24254365)

---

## long answer (csvkit + csvtool)

### the input

`in2csv -f json` expects *a list* of JSON objects, so you need to wrap the single object (`{...}`) into square brackets (`[{...}]`).

On POSIX compatible shells, write

```
echo "[$the_json]"
```

which will print

```
[{
  "whatever": 2342,
  "otherwise": 119,
  "and": 1,
  "so": 2,
  "on": 3
}]
```

### the csvkit command

You may pipe the above data directly into `in2csv`. However, you might run into issues with the ”*type inference*“ (CSV data interpretation) feature of csvkit:

```
$ echo "[$the_json]" | in2csv -f json
whatever,otherwise,and,so,on
2342,119,True,2,3
```

`1` has become `True`. For details, see the [Tips and Troubleshooting](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tricks.html#csv-data-interpretation) part of the docs. It's suggested to turn off type inference using the `-I` option:

```
$ echo "[$the_json]" | in2csv -I -f json
whatever,otherwise,and,so,on
2342,119,1,2,3
```

Now the result is as expected

### transpose the data

Still, you need to [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the data. The csvkit docs [say](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html):

> To transpose CSVs, consider [csvtool](http://colin.maudry.com/csvtool-manual-page/).

(`csvtool` is available on [github](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-csv), [opam](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/csv/), [debian](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/csvtool) and probably other distribution channels.)

Using csvkit + csvtool, your final command looks like this:

```
echo "[$the_json]" | in2csv -I -f json | csvtool transpose -
```

with the hyphen (`-`) meaning to take the data from `stdin`. This is the result:

```
whatever,2342
otherwise,119
and,1
so,2
on,3
```

### that's it.

I think there is no one-liner solution with `csvtool` only, you'll need `in2csv`. You may, however, use `jq` instead, see the short answer.

FTR, I'm using csvkit version *1.0.3*.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tested the first posted answer works! But it is a bit confusing because "[$the_json]" means the raw content of the json. So an example of command could be this:

```
echo '[{"a":"b","c":"d"}]' | in2csv -I -f json | csvtool transpose -
```

and if you want to do it with a file name instead, for instance  myfile.json one can add the brackets with a sed command and pipe it to in2csv:

```
sed -e '1s/^/[/' -e 's/$/,/' -e '$s/,$/]/' myfile.json | in2csv -I -f json > myfile.csv
```

Example with the full transposition command:

```
sed -e '1s/^/[/' -e 's/$/,/' -e '$s/,$/]/' myfile.json | in2csv -I -f json | csvtool transpose - > myfile.csv
```

source: [How to add bracket at beginning and ending in text on UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126968/how-to-add-bracket-at-beginning-and-ending-in-text-on-unix)